# Using Puppeteer to grab multiple image URLs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am currently trying to utilize Puppeteer to grab the image src from a series of images on a page. I'm sure I'm just missing some basic understanding of how to properly get the src attribute. Here's what I've got so far:

```
const [img] = await page.$$('span.product-photo > img');
const src = await img.getProperty('src');
const imgURL = await src.jsonValue();

console.log(imgURL);
```

With this I am only grabbing the first image src. I apologize for how naive this question must be. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `const [img] = ...` pulls out the first image into the `img` variable. So, presumably, you should be able to do `const imgArray = await page.$$('span.product-photo > img');` and loop over `imgArray`. I leave the rest as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a starting point. I appreciate that instead of giving me the answer you, you encouraged me to investigate and learn on my own. Thank you again.